# Apache to docker with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, docker

Let's say i have server (Centos 7) with Apache as main 80 port listener. And there're some web-sites powered by this apache on 80 port. Also i have project built in docker containers, on one of container listener is nginx. Is it possible to proxy all requests to docker's nginx via my Apache daemon while other sites will be powered up?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Easy: install mod_proxy and in Apache domain.conf file add to VirtualHost block directive below:
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

where / is ur path to be proxied and 127.0.0.1:8080 is local ip and port of ur docker container with nginx